# I am trying to create a greedy algorithm but my code won't return a value at the end

Tags: c, computer-science, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    float x;
     printf("O hai! How much change is owed?\n");
    do
    {
        x = GetFloat();
        x = x * 100;
        return roundf(x);
        int c = 0;
        do
        { 
            return x = x - 25;
            return c = c + 1;
        }
        while (x >= 25);
        printf("%d coins\n", c);
    }
    while (x <= 0);
}
```

When I input a float such as .60 it is supposed to convert it to an integer then detect if it is greater than 25. This will be the first in a process of graduating decreases in coin from quarter to dime to nickel etc. but when I first tried to test it with printing out the value I got after the first sequence had been completed it returned nothing.

Comment: There are three-too-many `return` statements in that code.

Answer (score 5):

As soon as your program hits `return roundf(x);` it will stop (since `main` has returned), which is why it produces no output after reading the first number.

Comment: How would I remove the return on roundf(x) without it displaying the error message:    ignoring return value of function declared with const attribute [-Werror,-Wunused-value]
        roundf(x);

Comment: You shouldn't be returning it at all; see @cdlane's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code only needs one `return` statement, but it's the one you forgot.  The others are syntax errors so you'll want to review what it is that `return` actually does.  Your code has most of what you need, but not in the correct order.  The rework below does what you intended the code to do at this point and hints where to go next:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("O hai! How much change is owed?\n");

    float x = GetFloat();
    x = x * 100;
    x = roundf(x);

    int coins[] = { 25 };

    int coin = 0;

    do
    {
        int c = 0;

        while (x >= coins[coin])
        {
            x = x - coins[coin];
            c = c + 1;
        }

        printf("%d coins worth %d\n", c, coins[coin]);
    }
    while (--coin >= 0);

    return 0;
}
```

I.e. you need to expand the array `coins` to contain the other denominations and set the `coin` variable to the index of the largest coin in `coins`.  Each time through your loop, change `coin` to index the next largest coin until there aren't any more.

I changed your inner `do { ... } while()` to a simple `while() { ... }` loop as you can't assume a given coin will be needed to make change.